# Dynamically Add values to MS access database and retrieve them using variables

Tags: c#, winforms, ms-access

I have a MS access database with a table called tarriff_table. In this table I have two columns `upperLimit` & `perUnitCost`. I have a form to insert this values. Now I want to use these values to calculate in code. I have the structure of the code but I am unable to connect database values to the variables I used.

Here is the code.

```
double demandCharge, VAT,upperLimit1, upperLimit2; 
double perUnitCost1, perUnitCost2;
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
 double con_unit = 0, bill = 0, mcon_unit = 0, totalbill = 0;
 con_unit = double.Parse(textBox1.Text);
 mcon_unit = double.Parse(textBox2.Text);
 if (con_unit < upperLimit1)
 {
  bill = con_unit * perUnitCost1;
 }
 else if (con_unit < upperLimit2)
 {
  bill = (upperLimit1 * perUnitCost1) + ((con_unit - upperLimit1) * perUnitCost2);
 }
 else bill = (upperLimit1 * perUnitCost1) + ((upperLimit2 - upperLimit1) * perUnitCost2);

 totalbill = Math.Ceiling((((((bill + demandCharge) * VAT) 
           + (bill + demandCharge)) / (con_unit)) * (mcon_unit)));
 textBox3.Text = Convert.ToString(totalbill);
}
```

This is a part of the code. But I assume it can generate the problem I am facing. Here I want to connect upperLimit columns to upperLimit variable and perUnitCost column to perUnitCost variable. How can I do it?

I want  these variables(`upperLimit1`, `upperLimit2`, `perUnitCost1`, `PerUnitCost2`) value to be pulled from a database.

**Important Note:** In the code section `perUnitCost2` means the value of the second row of the `perUnitCost` column in the database.

**Note:** There is a work around possible by calculating all the values before inserting them into the database. by doing this compile time can be reduced to half. As the compiler doesn't have to insert values and again retrieve them perform calculation.

**2nd Note:** I have figured out that I need a connection string to connect to a database. I will like the moderators to close the topic.

Comment: What is the issue with this code? The code does not have anything related to Ms-Access Database.

Comment: I want connect this code's variables(upperLimit[],range[]) to database columns(upperLimit, perUnitCost) respectively. But I don't know how to do it? @ChetanRanpariya

Comment: And you don't know how to write code to connect to MS-Access Database and query values from the table?

Comment: I know how connect with a database manually. But I don't know how to store those values dynamically into a variable for using those in the code given above.

Comment: You need to share the code of database which you tried and tell us where you are stuck.  https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/read-microsoft-access-database-in-C-Sharp/  try using the approach mentioned in this article. You can read data to `OleDbDataReader` from MS-Access. And then loop thru it and populate values from reader to the array. Try it and come back if you have difficulty understanding it.. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29402911/storing-fields-from-a-database-in-an-array-c-sharp

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29402911/storing-fields-from-a-database-in-an-array-c-sharp

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to query MS Access database with C# application?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7958919/how-to-query-ms-access-database-with-c-sharp-application)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a work around of my question.

```
private void btnsave_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string path = Path.Combine(Environment.CurrentDirectory, "Tenant info.mdb");
        connect.ConnectionString = @"Provider=Microsoft.JET.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source="+ path;


        double con_unit = 0, bill = 0, presr = 0, prevr = 0, mcon_unit = 0, totalbill = 0;

        presr = double.Parse(textbox5.Text);
        prevr = double.Parse(textbox37.Text);
        con_unit = double.Parse(textbox38.Text);
        mcon_unit = ((presr) - (prevr));
        textBox2.Text = Convert.ToString(mcon_unit);
        if (con_unit < 75)
        {
            bill = con_unit * 3.8;
        }
        else if (con_unit < 200)
        {
            bill = (75 * 3.8) + ((con_unit - 75) * 5.14);
        }
        else if (con_unit < 300)
        {
            bill = (75 * 3.8) + (125 * 5.14) + ((con_unit - 200) * 5.36);
        }
        else if (con_unit < 400)
        {
            bill = (75 * 3.8) + (125 * 5.14) + (100 * 5.36) + ((con_unit - 300) * 5.63);
        }
        else if (con_unit < 600)
        {
            bill = (75 * 3.8) + (125 * 5.14) + (100 * 5.36) + (100 * 5.63) + ((con_unit - 400) * 8.70);
        }
        else if (con_unit < 600)
        {
            bill = (75 * 3.8) + (125 * 5.14) + (100 * 5.36) + (100 * 5.63) + (200 * 8.70) + (con_unit * 9.98);
        }
        else bill = (75 * 3.8) + (125 * 5.14) + (100 * 5.36) + (100 * 5.63) + (200 * 8.70) + ((con_unit - 600) * 9.98);

        totalbill = Math.Ceiling((((((bill + 70) * .05) + (bill + 70)) / (con_unit)) * (mcon_unit)));
        textBox3.Text = Convert.ToString(totalbill);

        tenantBillDataBindingSource.EndEdit();
        tenantBillDataTableAdapter.Update(this.tenant_InfoDataSet.TenantBillData);
        MessageBox.Show("Data Added to Database. Please Reopen the Form to Insert New Entry");
    }
```